# Copy Color over multiple Worksheets multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a row of Different colors from one Worksheet to another.

Im new to VBA with a Powershell background so I migth have overseen something.

Heres the Code that i've tried, but each time I try to use it I get the "run-time Error 1004". The thing is the Ranges work, I tried them without the For-Loop, it worked so both the Worksheets are active and the ranges work.

```vb
Sub VLANColor()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Übersicht")
    Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ports")

    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String
    Dim num1 As Integer
    Dim num2 As Integer
    Dim field1 As String
    Dim field2 As String

    str1 = M
    num1 = 2
    field1 = ""

    str2 = A
    num2 = 5
    field2 = ""


    For i = 1 To 5

        field1 = str1 & num1
        field2 = str2 & num2

        sh2.Range(field1).Interior.Color = sh1.Range(field2).Interior.Color

        num1 = num1 + 1
        num2 = num2 + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `str1 = "M"` and `str2 = "A"`. Strings are enclosed in quotes. Add `Option Explicit` to the very top of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and most important step: add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. Or even better, go to *Tools* > *Options* and check *Require Variable Declaration* and it will be added automatically for you going forward.

Second, add quotes around `String`s.

```
str1 = "M"

str2 = "A"
```

As is, `M` and `A` are undeclared variables and not the `String`s you want.

So `field1` and `field2` are really only `num1` and `num2`, and `2` and `5` are not valid `Range` references.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this from my phone so i couldn't check it, but the only part i'm not sure of is if the sh2.Cells actually works, if it doesn't, you should use the sh2.Range you used (i've given instructions on how to use Range() in my code)

I've wrote you a lot of comments that are meant to help :)

```
Option Explicit
'Option Explicit is pretty much necessary in your VBA code

Sub VLANColor()
    ' You can use the ":" to declare and instanciate on the same line, making it easier to read imo, but its just my opinion
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet : Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Übersicht")
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet : Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ports")

    ' You need to declare the i variable for your incoming For
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim str1 As String : str1 = "M"
    Dim str2 As String : str2 = "A"
    Dim num1 As Integer : num1 = 2
    Dim num2 As Integer : num2 = 5
    Dim field1 As String ' The default value of a String is "" (which is equal to the VBA constant vbNullString)
    Dim field2 As String ' The default value of a String is "" (which is equal to the VBA constant vbNullString)

    'This will help me in the for loop, you'll understand how
    Dim intColumnA As Integer : intColumnA = 1
    Dim intColumnM As Integer : intColumnM = 13

    For i = 1 To 5 ' Consider : For i = 1 To num2
        ' For future use : CStr() converts a numerical to a String
        'field1 = str1 & CStr(num1) 
        'field2 = str2 & CStr(num2)
        ' but we wont need it anymore

        'sh2.Range(field1).Interior.Color = sh1.Range(field2).Interior.Color
        ' Range() cannot be used like that, but you can do as follows

        ' Using Cells(column, row) returns a range representing 1 cell
        ' or you can use Range(Cells(column, row), Cells(column, row)) to have multiple cells
        sh2.Cells(intColumnA, num1).Interior.Color  = sh1.Cells(intColumnM, num2).Interior.Color

        num1 = num1 + 1
        num2 = num2 + 1
    'Consider : "Next" alone, explicitly say "Next i" isnt necessary here, but it would become a necessity if you would like to do, for example, "Next i *2"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and helpfull tips! Range() acctually works with the column and range together, I dont know why, maybe its because it's in Excel? Well it works, and I'm surely going to use some tips like the declaration and the Explicit Option!